# Remove the line in the file Which has only number in shell script

Tags: shell

I have one file which contain sequence of number in every line. I want to remove the line which has only number

I tried (to no avail):

```
$ cat -n input_file > output_file
```

My file contain

```
1 name
2
3 Age
4
5 state
6 city
```

i want the output as

```
1 name
3 Age
5 state
6 city
```

Comment: This queytion does not show any research effort

Comment: Is the first file you've shown us `input_file` or `output_file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple [`awk`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) formula would do:

```
cat input_file | awk ' ($2 != "") { print $N } '
```

Edit: Cleaner way from Tom's comment

```
awk ' ($2 != "") { print $0 } ' input_file
```

Comment: `N`  is undefined so will be coerced to `0`. If you want to refer to the whole line, use `$0` directly, or just write `print`. Also, there's no need to pipe cat to awk.

Comment: Thank you @J. Chomel and @ Tom Fenech

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use grep and look for lines with any characters.

testfile.txt:

```
1 name
2
3 Age
4
5 State
6 city
```

Then try:

```
grep '[a-zA-Z]' testfile.txt
1 name
3 Age
5 State
6 city
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with this file:

```
name

Age

state
city
```

You can skip the empty lines and add the numbers like this:

```
awk 'NF { print NR, $0 }' file
```

When the line contains any non-blank characters (i.e. anything other than spaces or tabs), print the line number followed by the contents of the line.

---

If the numbers are in the input file already, you can use this:

```
awk 'NF > 1' file
```

This prints any line with more than one field.